# Create HashMap where key equals most frequent first letter in a text, and value is a linked list of all words starting on that letter

Tags: java, arrays, string, hashmap

It is a homework I admit. But it's to hard for me, I need some suggestions please. Method `getWordsInLyrics()` splits the text to words. Now how to get the most frequent first letter, and the words starting at that letter ? Store it in `HashMap<String letter, LinkedList<String words >> wordBegins = new HashMap<>();` Must I use the `charAt(0)` ?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class LyricsCounter {

    private static final String LYRICS = "Dwunastu braci, wierzac w sny, zbadalo mur od marzen strony,\n" +
            "A poza murem plakal glos, dziewczecy glos zaprzepaszczony.\n" +
            "I pokochali glosu dzwiek i chetny domysl o Dziewczynie,\n" +
            "I zgadywali ksztalty ust po tym, jak spiew od zalu ginie...\n" +
            "Mowili o niej: \"lka, wiec jest!\" - I nic innego nie mowili,\n" +
            "I przezegnali caly swiat - i swiat zadumal sie w tej chwili...\n" +
            "Porwali mloty w twarda dlon i jeli w mury tluc z loskotem!\n" +
            "I nie wiedziala slepa noc, kto jest czlowiekiem, a kto mlotem?\n" +
            "\"O, predzej skruszmy zimny glaz, nim smierc Dziewczyne rdza powlecze!\" -\n" +
            "Tak, walac w mur, dwunasty brat do jedenastu innych rzecze.\n" +
            "Ale daremny byl ich trud, daremny ramion sprzeg i usil!\n" +
            "Oddali ciala swe na strwon owemu snowi, co ich kusil!\n" +
            "lamia sie piersi, trzeszczy kosc, prochnieja dlonie, twarze bledna...\n" +
            "I wszyscy w jednym zmarli dniu i noc wieczysta mieli jedna!\n" +
            "Lecz cienie zmarlych - Boze moj! - nie wypuscily mlotow z dloni!\n" +
            "I tylko inny plynie czas - i tylko mlot inaczej dzwoni...\n" +
            "I dzwoni w przod! I dzwoni wspak! I wzwyz za kazdym grzmi nawrotem!\n" +
            "I nie wiedziala slepa noc, kto tu jest cieniem, a kto mlotem?\n" +
            "\"O, predzej skruszmy zimny glaz, nim smierc Dziewczyne rdza powlecze!\" -\n" +
            "Tak, walac w mur, dwunasty cien do jedenastu innych rzecze.\n" +
            "Lecz cieniom zbraklo nagle sil, a cien sie mrokom nie opiera!\n" +
            "I powymarly jeszcze raz, bo nigdy dosc sie nie umiera...\n" +
            "I nigdy dosc, i nigdy tak, jak pragnie tego ow, co kona!...\n" +
            "I znikla tresc - i zginal slad - i powiesc o nich juz skonczona!\n" +
            "Lecz dzielne mloty - Boze moj - mdlej nie poddaly sie zalobie!\n" +
            "I same przez sie bily w mur, huczaly spizem same w sobie!\n" +
            "Huczaly w mrok, huczaly w blask i ociekaly ludzkim potem!\n" +
            "I nie wiedziala slepa noc, czym bywa mlot, gdy nie jest mlotem?\n" +
            "\"O, predzej skruszmy zimny glaz, nim smierc Dziewczyne rdza powlecze!\" -\n" +
            "Tak, walac w mur, dwunasty mlot do jedenastu innych rzecze.\n" +
            "I runal mur, tysiacem ech wstrzasajac wzgorza i doliny!\n" +
            "Lecz poza murem - nic i nic! Ni zywej duszy, ni Dziewczyny!\n" +
            "Niczyich oczu ani ust! I niczyjego w kwiatach losu!\n" +
            "Bo to byl glos i tylko - glos, i nic nie bylo oprocz glosu!\n" +
            "Nic - tylko placz i zal i mrok i niewiadomosc i zatrata!\n" +
            "Takiz to swiat! Niedobry swiat! Czemuz innego nie ma swiata?\n" +
            "Wobec klamliwych jawnie snow, wobec zmarnialych w nicosc cudow,\n" +
            "Potezne mloty legly w rzad, na znak spelnionych godnie trudow.\n" +
            "I byla zgroza naglych cisz. I byla proznia w calym niebie!\n" +
            "A ty z tej prozni czemu drwisz, kiedy ta proznia nie drwi z ciebie?";

    private static String[] getWordsInLyrics() {
        return LYRICS.split("\\W+");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, LinkedList<String>> wordBegins = new HashMap<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have all the info you need. Where, exactly, are you stuck?

Comment: Now I have an array of words. Next step I think is to count the frequency of the first letter of each word ? Count the charAt(0) and which char is it ?

Comment: Yes, use a `for` loop. For each word in the array, get the first letter - possibly converting to lower case. Then check your map to see if that letter is in there. If not, create a `LinkedList` and add it to the hash map with the key being the letter. Lastly, add the word to the list.

Comment: Note that `charAt` returns a `char` but your map uses `String`. You either need to convert the `char` to `String` or use `word.substring(0, 1)`

Comment: It is a bit strange that you must use Map to store only SINGLE key -> value pair (even if value is linked list). If instead we would group all words with same starting character under key which would be that character like `a -> [a, ab, ac, ..]; b->[ba, bab, ...]` we could easily tell which character was used most often at start by comparing amount of words in each list (and that would be my guess what your homework is about).

Comment: I'm trying  ```if (wordBegins.containsKey(arr[i].substring(0,1))) {
                    wordBegins.put(arr[i].substring(0,1), null); ```' but insert LinkedList instead of null ?

Comment: `String firstLetter = arr[i].substring(0,1); if (!wordBegins.containsKey(firstLetter)) { wordBegins.put(firstLetter, new LinkedList<String>()); }`

Comment: Thank You Johnny this is good. If one more hint You could give me how to insert the words that start with searched letter to the LinekList?

Comment: `wordBegins.get(firstLetter).add(arr[i]);`

Comment: Thanks for the answers Johnny. The topic is too hard for me. I got to get back to basics. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most frequent character and its frequency can be easily tracked while populating the map, then appropriate word list is retrieved after the loop:

```java
Map<Character, LinkedList<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
char maxChar = ' ';
int maxFreq = 0;
for (String word : LYRICS.split("\\W+")) {
    char letter = Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(0));
    map.computeIfAbsent(letter, k -> new LinkedList<>()).add(word);
    int freq = map.get(letter).size();
    if (maxFreq < freq) {
        maxFreq = freq;
        maxChar = letter;
    }
}
System.out.println("Most frequent: " + maxChar + "; frequency = " + maxFreq);
System.out.println(map.get(maxChar));
```

Output:

```
Most frequent: i; frequency = 47
[I, i, I, I, innego, I, i, i, I, innych, ich, i, ich, I, i, I, inny, i, inaczej, I, I, I, I, innych, I, I, i, I, i, i, I, i, I, innych, I, i, i, I, i, i, i, i, i, i, innego, I, I]
```

If uppercase and lowercase letters are counted separately without applying `Character.toLowerCase`:

```
char letter = word.charAt(0);
```

then the champion is:

```
Most frequent: n; frequency = 38
[niej, nic, nie, nie, noc, nim, na, noc, nie, nawrotem, nie, noc, nim, nagle, nie, nigdy, nie, nigdy, nigdy, nich, nie, nie, noc, nie, nim, nic, nic, ni, niczyjego, nic, nie, niewiadomosc, nie, nicosc, na, naglych, niebie, nie]
```

---

Top 10 most frequent first letters may be output using Stream API to sort the entries in the map by the size of the lists:

```java
final int mx = maxFreq;
map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.<Map.Entry<Character, LinkedList<String>>>comparingInt(e -> e.getValue().size())
        .reversed()
        .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
    )
    .limit(10)
    .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " = " + e.getValue().size()));
```

Output (case-insensitive check):

```
i = 47
n = 42
s = 36
w = 34
d = 31
m = 30
p = 28
t = 26
z = 25
c = 20
```

Comment: Thanks for the great post. Is there a way to eliminate duplicates in the solution, so to avoid i i i i i  etc.. ?